# Can a pipe be overwritten?

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, fork

I'm trying to develop communication among multiple processes, but I'm not sure if I can do it with using only one pipe. 
Once the pipe is initiated and used like this:

```
int fd[2];
int pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){
    //do the writing
}else if(pid > 0){
    //read what's written by child
}
```

Can the write head of the pipe be overwritten by the child process for a newer value? Or is it just for one-use only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no pipe in your code example

Comment: You seem to have forgotten `pipe(fd);`

Comment: Either process can write to `fd[0]`, and what they write will be read from `fd[1]`.

Comment: But if you want to communicate among different pairs of processes, you need separate pipes for each one. Otherwise all the messages will be mixed together.

Comment: ... or even if you want *bidirectional* communication between just two processes.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you may be confusing the file descriptor *value* identifying one end of a pipe with the *variable(s)* in which it is stored.  The storage for the value is incidental, and its contents may be replaced with something else if and when you like.  That has no bearing on the significance of the file descriptor value.